# How to create a terms of service page for my app

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a terms of service page for my app, how to display my page exactly like the image below? (the texts are scrollable).

[image]

Comment: Content of "Terms of service" getting from any webservice or static ?

Comment: Load data in textview if you are calling webservice.simply
textview.text = @"text of webservice"

Comment: paste response in TextEditor .format it like whatever you want and paste in text of textview property

Comment: I am getting contents via api.

Comment: But what if the content length will vary overtime , then using uitextview is recommended or not?

Comment: then take a web view and open that URL in webview

Comment: if u take web view then that automatically scroll down according to content

Comment: @Rinki Response is in html format? or simply text?

Comment: @Divine Child HTML format

Comment: NSAttributedString * attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[@"Your Response" dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding] options:@{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType } documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
            txtDesc.attributedText = attrStr;

Comment: @Sapana Ranipa HTML format

Comment: @Rinki try this code

Comment: @Rinki check updated comment.if find issue let me know

Comment: @ Divine Child i will check and confirm you soon. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130491/discussion-between-divine-child-and-rinki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

```
let encodedString: String = "<html><head></head><body><ul><li><input type='image' name='input1' value='string1value' class='abc' /></li><li><input type='image' name='input2' value='string2value' class='def' /></li></ul><span class='spantext'><b>Hello World 1</b></span><span class='spantext'><b>Hello World 2</b></span><a href='example.com'>example(English)</a><a href='example.co.jp'>example(JP)</a></body>";

    let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
        NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
    ]

    let attrStr = try! NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
    print(attrStr)
    textView.attributedText = attrStr
```

Comment: Found solution?

Comment: @Divine Child Yes Thanks.